# How to show a loader on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```html
<input type="submit" 
       name="sql"
       id="sql"
       value="Import Database"
       onclick="myFunction1()" 
       class="btn btn-danger"">
```

I have a button called import database. When I click the button the database will be downloaded. It takes some time. I want to show a loader while clicking the button. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Find a javascript plugin which allows to do that, internet is full of them.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. jQuery has some I believe. It depends on what type of loader you want - do you want a full-screen loader, or just a loader on the button?  We have changed the name of the button on click to "Processing..." and disabled it in a few projects.  It all needs JavaScript of some sort. Also, are you using AJAX? Did you search around on here for a previous answer? I'd be willing to bet this is a duplicate question.

Comment: The only way to do this is to do an ajax call that does your db loading and shows the loading image (preventing the default submit of the form so you stay on the same page), Then in your ajax success or fail, you can then hide the loading icon again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<div id="loader_div" class="loader_div"></div>`  on `index.php` file

Add below css:-

```
.loader_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity:0.7;
  display:none;
  background: lightgrey url('../../../images/youloadergif.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Now you can show and hide your loader by below script:-

```
jQuery(".loader_div").show();
jQuery(".loader_div").hide();
```

Hope this will help you.

> Note: Don't forget to place your gif on server and give a proper path
>   in background css.

Thanks,

Comment: You should not really answer questions with technologies that have not been mentioned in question, unless you ask if it is ok in the comments first

Comment: apologize @pete